# Vimeo's couch mode ported to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, youtube, vimeo, android-video-player

Is there any attempt to re-make something like Vimeo's couch mode http://vimeo.com/couchmode in jQuery?

I mean a video player which you feed with video links (either from vimeo or youtube) and acts like vimeos couch mode or youtube 's lean back.

Comment: this isn't the type of question to ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: @samccone, read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq, not programming related, you are making a request.

Comment: @jakub ... this is a question asking about a general implementation of something ... I think it is fine

Comment: well, a question remains a question! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familier with an exact clone... but you could write your own without much difficulty

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

http://vimeo.com/api/docs/advanced-api

basically you would write a script to query their api's .. return the video .. play it ect ..

hope this helps

Comment: I think I'll build my own... just when I get some time.. thx samcone